# Loading fragment into FrameLayout on activity start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using one main activity and one FrameLayout which is used for fragment displaying:
[image: My App Layout]

My problem is, since I'm using FrameLayout and not Fragment, fragment is not loaded automaticaly into my FrameLayout. Yes I can simply add the fragment to my layout in onCreate but problem is that this fragment is loaded on every orientation change as well, replacing current fragment (with the one i specified in onCreate).

Changing fragment

```
mainWindowFragment = new Login();
MainWindowFragmentChange("LoginView");
```

MainWindowFragmentChange function

```
private void MainWindowFragmentChange(String fragmentTag)
{
    mainWindowFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction = mainWindowFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right, R.animator.slide_out_left);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFragment, mainWindowFragment, fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

My activity_main_window.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context=".MainWindow"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--<TextView
            android:id="@+id/countOfFragments"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Fragments count in back stack: 0"/>-->

        <FrameLayout
            android:name="com.schwabe.vossloh.linahome.GroupView"
            android:id="@+id/mainActivityFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_items"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainWindow.java

```
public class MainWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView btn_Menu;
private ImageView btn_addLight;
private AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat menuToArrow;
private AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat arrowToMenu;

private boolean isShowingNavDraver = false;

private DrawerLayout navDrawerLayout;

private Fragment mainWindowFragment;
private FragmentManager mainWindowFragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction mainWindowFragmentTransaction;

private TextView countOfFragments;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    navDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(this.navDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START))
    {
        this.navDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        btn_Menu.setImageDrawable(arrowToMenu);
        arrowToMenu.start();
        isShowingNavDraver = !isShowingNavDraver;
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_window);

    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

    mainWindowFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    btn_Menu = findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
    navDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_layout);

    menuToArrow = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.animation_menu_to_arrow);
    arrowToMenu = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.animation_arrow_to_menu);
    btn_Menu.setImageDrawable(menuToArrow);

    btn_Menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {                
            if(!isShowingNavDraver && !isFragmentActive("QRreader"))
            {
                btn_Menu.setImageDrawable(menuToArrow);
                menuToArrow.start();
                navDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                isShowingNavDraver = !isShowingNavDraver;
            }
            else if(isShowingNavDraver && !isFragmentActive("QRreader"))
            {
                btn_Menu.setImageDrawable(arrowToMenu);
                arrowToMenu.start();
                navDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                isShowingNavDraver = !isShowingNavDraver;
            }
            else if(isFragmentActive("QRreader"))
            {
                btn_Menu.setImageDrawable(arrowToMenu);
                arrowToMenu.start();
                mainWindowFragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }
        }
    });

    final NavigationView navDrawerView = findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer);
    navDrawerView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {                      
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.group_view_menuitem:
                            mainWindowFragment = new GroupView();
                            MainWindowFragmentChange(menuItem, "GroupView");
                            break;
                        case R.id.list_view_menuitem:
                            mainWindowFragment = new ListView();
                            MainWindowFragmentChange(menuItem, "ListView");
                            break;
                        case R.id.login_menuitem:
                            mainWindowFragment = new Login();
                            MainWindowFragmentChange(menuItem, "LoginView");
                            break;
                    }
                    isShowingNavDraver = !isShowingNavDraver;
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );

    btn_addLight = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_light);
    btn_addLight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(isFragmentActive("GroupView") || isFragmentActive("ListView")) {
                btn_Menu.setImageDrawable(menuToArrow);
                menuToArrow.start();
                mainWindowFragment = new QRreader();
                MainWindowFragmentRightToLeft("QRreader");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void MainWindowFragmentChange(MenuItem menuItem, String fragmentTag)
{
    mainWindowFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    cleanBackStack();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction = mainWindowFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFragment, mainWindowFragment, fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.commit();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    btn_Menu.setImageDrawable(arrowToMenu);
    arrowToMenu.start();

    navDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}


private void MainWindowFragmentChange(String fragmentTag)
{
    mainWindowFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction = mainWindowFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFragment, mainWindowFragment, fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.commit();
}

private void MainWindowFragmentRightToLeft(String fragmentTag)
{
    mainWindowFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction = mainWindowFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right, R.animator.slide_out_left);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFragment, mainWindowFragment, fragmentTag);
    mainWindowFragmentTransaction.commit();
}

private boolean isFragmentActive(String nameOfFragment)
{
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(nameOfFragment);
    return fragment != null;
}


private void cleanBackStack()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mainWindowFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i)
        mainWindowFragmentManager.popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: post all your class code.

Comment: update: added my main window class code

Comment: I think that you problem is replace the fragment every time with `mainWindowFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFragment, mainWindowFragment, fragmentTag);`.  I can't help you now, but if nobody reply your question I can try help you other time.

Comment: Problem relies i beleive in calling it in my activity onCreate according to activity lifecycle. [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) So what I need is basicly a method that will be loaded only once after activity is first time launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android recreates activity on orientation change and FragmentManager takes care of attaching your fragments in places they were before activity was destroyed.

So you explicitly need not add/remove/replace fragments on orientation change.

You can check if the activity was recreated with the following -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if(savedInstanceState == null) { 
        // add/replace your fragment as you would do the first time
    } else {
        // activity is recreated due to any configuration change . here the fragment will be automatically attached by the fragment manager. You can fetch that fragment by findFragmentByTag(String tag) and then use it.
    }
}
```

Comment: I also found solution where you create class with global variables and simply do `if(GlobalVariables.mainWindowFistLoad) {
            loadFirstFragment();
            GlobalVariables.mainWindowFistLoad = false;
        }` but this solution is more elegant for sure. Thanks mate!